# how to add access token in angularjs http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

i am new in developing a website using angularJS as my client-side and i am trying to access my JSON thru API call with $http.get method for angular.

my issue is that my API call requires an Access Token. i always get this error whenever i try to refresh my page.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://unexus-api-dev-3urcgetdum.elasticbeanstalk.com/drugstores. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8888' is therefore not allowed access.

i am currently using this code to fetch my data.

```js
myApp.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("http://unexus-api-dev-3urcgetdum.elasticbeanstalk.com/drugstores")
    .then(function(response) {
      $scope.names = response.data.records;
    });
});
```

how do i insert an access token on the $http.get method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into a **SOP** issue that is described here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

You should have a look here:

1. [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)
2. [Same origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863744/same-origin-policy)
3. [XMLHttpRequest Same Origin Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19673450/xmlhttprequest-same-origin-policy)

Answer (score 5):

It depends on how your API get this access token. The most popular option is to just add specyfic header to your request

```
var req = {
   method: 'POST',
   url: 'http://example.com',
   headers: {
      'Authorization': 'access token'
   },
}

$http(req).then(function(){...}, function(){...});
```

you can also add it globally

```
module.run(function($http) {
  $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic YmVlcDpib29w';
});
```

or by using Angular interceptors
http://www.diwebsity.com/2015/12/17/interceptor-in-angular/

Comment: i still get the same error even if i did all you said.